# Parsing JSON array with a sub-array with GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Say I have a JSON string like:

`{"title":"aaa","url":"bbb","image":{"url":"ccc","width":"100","height":"200"}, ...`

My accessor:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class accessorClass {

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("url")
    private String url;

    @SerializedName("image")
    private String image;

    // how do I place the sub-arrays for the image here?
    ...


    public final String get_title() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public final String get_url() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public final String get_image() {
        return this.image;
    }

    ...

}
```

And my main:

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(jstring).getAsJsonArray();

            ArrayList<accessorClass > aens = new ArrayList<accessorClass >();

            for(JsonElement obj : Jarray )
            {
                accessorClass ens = gson.fromJson( obj , accessorClass .class);
                aens.add(ens);
            }
```

What do you think would be the best way to get those sub-arrays for the image here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI if your JSON is an array: `{"results:":[{"title":"aaa","url":"bbb","image":{"url":"ccc","width":"100","height":"20...},{}]}`

Then you need a wrapper class:

```
class WebServiceResult {
    public List<AccessorClass> results;
}
```

If your JSON isn't formatted like that, then your For loop you created will do it, (if not a little clunky, would be better if your JSON is formed like above).

Create an Image class

```
class ImageClass {
    private String url;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Then change your `AccessorClass`

```
    @SerializedName("image")
    private ImageClass image;

    // Getter and setter
```

Then GSON the incoming String

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
AccessorClass object = gson.fromJson(result, AccessorClass.class);
```

Job done.

Comment: No problem.. added a bit more to it to explain how your json should be formatted but should work as you had it. :)